# Splitting words in pairs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have words as following:

```
pairs.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
is_allow_note=0
is_address_override=1
solution_type=Sole
token=EC-17A5206955089011A
```

I want to make them pairs as `(is_allow_note, 0),..., (token, EC-17A5206955089011A)` such that I can apply groupByKey/ reduceByKey on them.

I am very new to Spark. Can someone help with this?

Comment: `val p =  "([^=]+)=([^=]+)".r; _ match { case p(x, y) => Some((x, y))}` or `_.split("=")`; ...`? Still, it looks like a  code requests. At least try to explain what you've tried / what problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function to map each row to a pair (tuple), like:

```
pairs.map(s => {
   val substrings = s.split("=")
   (subStrings(0), substrings(1))
})
```